# How can a vector be decomposed into its perpendicular plus a sum of basis functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, orthogonality

A vector $\mathbf{w}$ can be written to such a form:
$$\mathbf{w} = \sum_n a_n \mathbf{\phi}(\mathbf{x}_n) + \mathbf{w}_\perp$$
where $a_n$ is some real number as parameters, $\phi(\cdot)$ is a basis function mapping features nonlinearly ($\phi(\cdot$) has the same dimension as vector $\mathbf{w}$, and $\mathbf{x}_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector of $m$ features.

What is this transformation on $w$, is there any name for it? How come $\mathbf{w}$ can be decomposed to such two parts?

Comment: What is a basis function mapping? This appears to be a scalar function because of the absence of a bold type, but this cannot be.

Comment: $\phi(x_i) $ has the same dimension as vector $\mathbf{w}$. @TrialAndError

Comment: If you use bold to describe a vector, then you should be consistent. Right now you have $\phi$ which is not bold, and you have $a_n$ which is not bold. So there is ambiguity. Please edit your question.